# How do I make the 'tasks' in my web app editable?

Tags: javascript, html, sequelize.js, glitch-framework

When I press 'update' nothing happens. As there are more than one instances of the 'tasks', which is circled [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtmM9.png)). By the way, I am using sequelize as my backend.

The link to my code is:https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gunna-submit-this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit or update tasks on your page you could try this tutorial,if you find a way to implement this in your project is going to work ,comes in 2 chapters:
https://medium.com/@diogo.fg.pinheiro/simple-to-do-list-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-chapter-1-c645c7a27583

https://medium.com/@diogo.fg.pinheiro/simple-to-do-list-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-chapter-2-3780a1c5b039
In chapter 2 you learn about the delete and edit button.